# Google endpoints API authentication approach

Tags: java, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, access-token

I am looking for ways to secure my Google Cloud Endpoints for Java using custom authentication as one of the approaches apart from Google Authentication. Hence maintaining a Username and Password database in my application. Since it is using REST API, I am looking to use Access Tokens keys to authenticate my users when they are calling the API.

So far I tried using Spring security to create an access token and handle logins but it seems that it is too bulky to implement.
I was thinking about Apache Shiro before I end up developing an access token system myself.

What approach do you suggest I take?

Thanks!